# how to add zoom-in and zoom-out feature in aframe react js

Tags: reactjs, aframe

I have created an image viewer using aframe. the image is of type 360 view image.

i've created the complete viewer, now my main task is to add zoom-in and out feature in that image.

i tried the custom functions to implement this feature, also the library called `aframe-event-set-component` 
but noting worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.